# Use PixelIdxList values to show specific objects in an image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have a binary image that I want to omit those objects in it which their length/width ratio is more than a threshold. I used codes below to extract some properties of the objects:

```
labeledImage = bwlabel(my_image, 8);
regioninfo = regionprops(labeledImage,'MajorAxisLength','MinorAxisLength','PixelIdxList');
lengths = [regioninfo.MajorAxisLength];   %array
widths = [regioninfo.MinorAxisLength];    %array
logidx = (lengths ./ widths) < threshold;
extracted_objs = regioninfo(logidx);      % 24*1 structer
```

Now I need to know **how can I exactly use PixelIdxList values to show the remaining parts**??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Again, answering my own question...found the answer somewhere else! put it here for thoese like me who might need:

```
labeledImage = bwlabel(my_image, 8);
regioninfo = regionprops(labeledImage,'MajorAxisLength','MinorAxisLength','PixelIdxList');
figure,vislabels(labeledImage ),title('Visualized labels of connected components');
lengths = [regioninfo.MajorAxisLength];   %array
widths = [regioninfo.MinorAxisLength];    %array
logidx = (lengths ./ widths) < threshold;
Keeper_Indexes=find(logidx);
Keeper_Building_Image=ismember(labeledImage,Keeper_Indexes);
figure,imshow(Keeper_Building_Image);title('thresholded image by Ratio');
```